# LED chandelier lights permanently dim

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

Our LED chandelier has 20 1.5w G4 bi-pin bulbs. About a month ago, all of the bulbs, in unison became very dim. We do not have a dimmer on this chandelier. I noticed that sometimes when I'd turn on the chandelier the bulbs would go back to being bright, but it was only a matter of seconds or minutes before they would return to their dimly lit state. This isn't a fading action, they all dim at once and suddenly.

Now, my chandelier's bulbs will not return to their intended brightness at all and they are all permanently dim.

I purchased some new bulbs and replaced one to test if the bulbs went bad. The new bulb showed the exact same dimness as all the other bulbs so I returned the new bulbs.

I contacted an electrician and his answer was to simply buy a new chandelier. Unfortunately the one we have or comparable ones are roughly $1,000.

I'd like to save the one we have if there are some reasonable troubleshooting techniques.

I'm no electrician, but is there something similar to a ballast that could have gone out? Are these replaceable?

One other thing I should note is that we have a pond with a pond pump that comes on daily. When it comes on, many of the lights in the house dim briefly. I wondered if this power draw could have ruined the chandelier. Again, the electrician I talked to seemed to dismiss that this was a concern. I want to know that if I buy a new chandelier of fix the existing one that I won't be right back into this same issue due to the power draw that I just mentioned.

Thank you!

#### Update:

This is for 120v

#### Update 2:

Below are photos of the electrical connections. I see two exposed wires. I assume these are ground, but I don't *think* they were connected to anything. Could that have been the problem? It would be odd though that the chandelier worked for months and months with no disturbances and just finally go dim.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you in 120V-land (North America, Japan) or the rest of the 230V world?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, I just updated the question to indicate that I'm in North America / 120v

Comment: What else - other lights, receptacles, etc. - is on the **same breaker**?

Comment: Your wall plug line voltage is 120V, and the G4 bulbs are 12V, so there is a transformer / LED driver somewhere between the wall wiring and the bulbs. It's a small box where the line wire goes into and the bulb wires come out of. Can you include a picture of it please?

Comment: Yes, can you find the transformer/driver that feeds this fixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Power supply is shot

G4 lamps are all 12V (least, all the ones I found).

All 20 lamps are behaving exactly the same. It can't be because of all the lamps being in series, since that would be 240V worth of lamps, and you're in 120V-land.  (that would be 2 series strings so only half would fail).   So cross that off the list.

What remains is there is a 12V power supply somewhere.  That is the common thread. Clearly, it is failing.

Comment: Is this something that is reasonable to repair? I'm trying to also ascertain if the electrician I talked to is just blowing off the idea of repairing it or if it actually isn't worth the time (keep in mind, the chandelier is expensive). Any tips for a completely lay person would be appreciated!

Comment: @RyanGriffith repair the transformer? No, but you should be able to get a replacement.

Comment: The electrician is operating in "I only do the wiring, I don't fix appliances or fixtures" mode, just like many appliance people will be (often required by licensing rules, unlike the other way around) "I only fix appliances, I don't do the wiring".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, is that to say that this is something that should be attempted by an "Appliance Repair" person? I.e. I should not attempt this myself? In short, I'm trying to find the most direct path to get this fixed ASAP and I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Not at all. Just saying that I have most definitely seen all types: Electricians who won't touch appliance repairs; appliance repairman who won't do any "real" electrical (and often for good reason); handymen who will do a little of everything, etc. IMHO, but laws really do vary on this, in your own home you should be able to do any of this yourself provided you know what you are doing, and that almost always is the case for the appliance/fixture side of things. Thanks to the internet, finding replacement parts - and even installation videos - is much easier than it used to be.

Comment: And both of the answers are almost certainly correct - "all bulb" problems with no other problems is almost certainly going to be driver/transformer/etc. as opposed to 120V electric supply problem.

Comment: @RyanGriffith Admonishing people not to DIY things is pretty much the opposite of what we do around here lol. Yeah, if you can get it down, snap some pix of the data on the power supply and we can advise.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, thank you for the clarification. I've updated my post to show what I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the LED driver. You can take it down and try to find a compatible driver equivalent to the specs and replace that part alone.